# What does "position" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I guess it means **porfolio**. Is it correct?

Still, millionaire investors were opportunistic during the market declines. A majority bought or added to their positions in stocks, mutual funds and ETFs since March. Only 17% reduced their positions as the market bottomed, while 11% sold their entire positions.

Source: https://www.cnbc.com/2020/05/27/millionaires-bet-that-stocks-will-take-at-least-another-year-to-recover.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/position.asp):

> A **position** is the amount of a security, commodity or currency which is owned by an individual, dealer, institution, or other fiscal entity. They come in two types: short positions, which are borrowed and then sold, and long positions, which are owned and then sold. Depending on market trends, movements and fluctuations, a position can be profitable or unprofitable.

Comment: Clarifying "portfolio", AHD gives; 4. A group of investments held by an investor, investment company, or financial institution. So, that sounds like all of someone's positions or other investments as a group.